# Are players creatures? What are creatures?

Tags: dnd-5e

The cleric ability Preserve life says the following:

> Starting at 2nd level, you can use your Channel Divinity to heal the badly injured.
>
> As an action, you present your holy Symbol and evoke Healing energy that can >restore a number of hit points equal to five times your cleric level.
>
> Choose any creatures within 30 feet of you, and divide those hit
>   points among them. This feature can restore a creature to no more than
>   half of its hit point maximum. You can’t use this feature on an Undead
>   or a construct.

I can't seem to find a straight definition of "creature." Can the cleric heal Player Characters, humanoid NPCs, etc? A layman definition of 'creature' to me would mean any non-humanoid / monstrous enemy to the characters. But it doesn't make much sense to be able to heal only your enemies.

So are the players considered creatures?